# Warning : procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: plsql, procedure

i can't compile. i don't know what is the problem. pls help.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VERIFY

    IS 
    LNO DRIVER.L#%TYPE;

    BEGIN
       SELECT L# INTO LNO
       FROM ADMIN JOIN DRIVER 
       ON ADMIN.E# = DRIVER.E#(+);

       IF LNO != NULL THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("NOT NULL");
       END IF;

    COMMIT;

    END VERIFY;
```

Comment: For future reference: `SHOW ERRORS`

Comment: btw, the LNO != NULL condition will _never_ be satisfied. The check you should be doing is `LNO is NOT NULL`

Answer (score 3):

`(+)` can't be used in `ON` part of `JOIN`.

Either use it in `WHERE` section:

```
SELECT L# 
INTO LNO
FROM ADMIN, 
     DRIVER 
WHERE ADMIN.E# = DRIVER.E#(+);
```

or use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`:

```
SELECT L# 
INTO LNO
FROM ADMIN
LEFT JOIN DRIVER ON ADMIN.E# = DRIVER.E#;
```

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3175

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT NULL');
```

instead of

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("NOT NULL");
```

(i.e. single quotes)

Comment: LINE/COL ERROR
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1/82     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DRIVER" when expecting one of
         the following:
         , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where
         connect

Comment: Errors for PROCEDURE VERIFYIS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1/21     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LNO" when expecting one of the
         following:
         ( ; is with authid as cluster compress order using compiled
         wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined
         result_cache
         The symbol "(" was substituted for "LNO" to continue.

1/39     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
      := ) , default character